# How can I prolong the life of beer in a growler?

Tags: preservation, growlers, freshness

Beer in a growler typically lasts for 24 hours or less, depending on how full the growler is, how many times it's opened over that period of time, and how efficient the seal is on the lid. Are there ways of prolonging the life in a growler or at least seal it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not much one can do, at least using only household products.

While filling, using a counterpressure bottle filler would maximize the longevity of the beer as well as filling the beer while it's very cold, near its freezing point ~29 degrees F (so that its CO<sub>2</sub> is maximally dissolved), if you have a choice in the matter (likely not).

Once opening the growler over multiple sessions, however, it's not the ineffectiveness of the seal (using a swing-top growler should do just fine) as much as it is the growing amounts of air that get sealed within.

There exist several products funded and developed via Kickstarter you might want to check out:

- [FreshCap](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/380990171/the-freshcaptm-hits-the-beer-scene-co2-injection-s?ref=live) (See [retailers](http://thezythosproject.com/retailers/) for purchase.)
- [The Growler Saver](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1691296505/the-growler-savertm-the-last-pour-is-as-good-as-th) (See [retailers](http://www.growlersaver.com/where-to-buy.html) for purchase.)
- [Drink Tanks](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/584321487/the-perfect-beer-drinking-vessel-and-private-keg) (See [store](http://www.drinktanks.com/products/growler-accessories/) for direct purchase.)
- [TapIt Cap](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1732077870/the-tapit-cap-the-beer-growlers-best-friend) (See [store](http://tapitcap.com/shop/) for direct purchase.)

Comment: That was the answer I was expecting ;) Drink Tanks looks like the most suitable solution because of its CO₂ pressure seal and steel growler.

Comment: @remus - Haha, oh the fun of private betas :-)